# Run VLOOKUP on multiple data sets, conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, formulas, vba

[image: sheet1a]
I'm not exactly sure if I would use a VLOOKUP here, but this what I want to do.

I have data in sheet 1.  **Sales orders that have multiple items.  For instance Sales order 1 has 3 lines.  Line 1, 2, 3.  Line 1, 2, 3, has a quantity of 2, 100, 50.**  This sheet is my open sales orders only

Since Sales Order HS12228 Line Item 2 Quantity of 50 has been fully invoiced below (fully invoiced Yes), then it should be considered shipped (Shipped, Y) on the same information above.

[image: sheet2a]
I have data in sheet 2.  **Same exact data as above, but in addition, I have a field that tells me if any of those lines on Sales order 1 has been invoiced.**  This sheet is all open sales orders, regardless if its open or closed.

If a sales order line is invoiced, then I know it is shipped.  So since I can't see what has been shipped in Sheet 1, I would like to look in sheet 2 and see what has been invoiced against the sales order and bring back a "Yes" for invoiced, which i will call "shipped" in sheet 1.

I know in order for it to return the right match, the sales order and sales order quantity in sheet 1 have to match the sales order and qty ordered in sheet 2.  I've attached pics for reference

[image: sheet1]

[image: sheet2]

Comment: I'm going to match the text up with the image.

Comment: I've went back in and edited it.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I've tried VLOOKUP, but i don't know how to string more than one together when looking at identical data and knowing how to tell it to look at more data instead of it always bringing back the first match it finds.  I don't know what a helper column is.  I prefer sheet formula.

Comment: Okay, I get it.  So basically merge the columns together and the run the vlookup like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,'Sales Order Detail Browse'!$A$1:$U$10884,21,0)
```